# automatic configuration from code c# for ceate IIS service or something

Tags: c#, iis

I need to raise a service for using the compilation of my application without manually configure it the IIS in windows

one versión of my application web have data base internal, its necesary for worked offline.
The user does not manually configure the IIS service.

Is like a desktop app, but for the web app, where you can use it from local computer, just having the app compilation

My app is MVC C# with SQL Server.

Comment: Not sure if I got you right: are you trying to run web app on your local IIS and access it via localhost URL?

Comment: In most cases you should self host the web app yourself (ASP.NET Web API/SignalR, or ASP.NET Core supports that), instead of hosting on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

The docker could create a image whcih contains the IIS settings and application file.

Then the customer could use docker direclty run the image without using any other setting.

More details about how to generate the docker file using vs and how to use it, you could refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker

How to install the run docker with asp.net application.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/